# How to use triage field in CMMI work items

Tags: tfs

When is the triage field used in the CMMI workitems like Change Request and Bug in TFS 2010?

For example: when a developer has been assigned to work on a Change Request and it has been triaged by the CBB and he finds out that the CR has not enough info to go further, must the CR be set to Proposed with a triage field "More info" ?

Answer (score 1):

In our process the developers provide input into the triage process such as providing an estimate and identifying dependencies. If they have identified they require further information, then they would set the field to "More Info" and such CRs or Bugs would not be triaged at the CBB and thus the work items would remain at "Proposed". If your process is that changes and bugs are prioritised without the input from the development team, then I would ask if getting this further information would change the priority? If so, then definitely send the work item back to "Proposed" and have the CBB review.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprocess/thread/d35595ff-a166-4d6d-979a-f3d2479374bd/